# Remove query string in url for homepage only (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uri

I tried to remove query string from my url on my homepage only.

Because when a visitor come from social, example: Facebook add this argument at the end of the url: ?fb=654616516546... and that breaks my website.

I have tried this but it overwrites all the url arguments on all the pages, I would like this rule to apply only to the homepage:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex /index.php?page=servers

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /   
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]*)=([^/]*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]     
</IfModule>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `^$` instead of  `(.*)` in the Rule's pattern  so that your rule applies only to the root URI .

```
RewriteRule ^$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```